# How to insert an array of objects as an argument of an array of objects parameter

Tags: arrays, typescript

> I'm shortening down my model and method, but either way it represents
>   my current problem.
>
> Model:

```
export class OrdersModel {
      constructor(public items: [{
                    itemName: string,
                    sellerUsername: string,
                    price: string,
                    image: string,
                    itemId: string,
                    cartId?: string
                  }]) {
      }
    }
```

> Method:

```
  checkOut() {
    let orderItems = [];
    for (let item of this.items) {
      orderItems.push({
        itemName: item[0].itemName,
        sellerUsername: item[0].sellerUsername,
        price: item[0].price,
        image: item[0].image,
        itemId: item[0].itemId
      });
    }
    const order = new OrdersModel(
      orderItems
    );
    this.userProfileService.addToOrders(order)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log(data);
        },
        error => console.error(error)
      );
  }
```

> I'm trying to add multiple items to an order. So the way I've
>   constructed my model is to have an array of objects (items), and then
>   store the items as an array of objects in the database. So I'm trying
>   to loop through my current array of items (the ones to be added to the
>   order), and add them to my `Orders` model. If there is an easier way
>   of doing this, please let me know. But this is my current idea of how
>   to add the array of items (cart Items) into the Order Model. Here is
>   my error of `orderItems` when using is as an argument in the method
>   checkOut():

```
Argument of type any[] is not assignable to parameter of type `[{
              itemName: string,
              sellerUsername: string,
              price: string,
              image: string,
              itemId: string,
              cartId?: string
            }]`
` Proper ‘0’ is missing in type any[]
```

> I understand that basically I can't assign the array type that I have, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the parameter to the constructor is not an array, it's actually  tuple, and tuples have a fixed size. Generally : `[type]` - tuple with one item of type `type`, `type[]` array of type. You can read more about tuples [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html)

```
 constructor(public items: {
              itemName: string,
              sellerUsername: string,
              price: string,
              image: string,
              itemId: string,
              cartId?: string
            }[]) {
}
```

**Note** I would change you design a bit to use a named interface, so that you can type `orderItems` correctly as well:

```
interface OrdersItemModel{
    itemName: string,
    sellerUsername: string,
    price: string,
    image: string,
    itemId: string,
    cartId?: string
}
export class OrdersModel {
    constructor(public items: OrdersItemModel[]) {
    }
}

function checkOut() {
    let orderItems: OrdersItemModel[] = [];
    for (let item of this.items) {
    orderItems.push({
        itemName: item[0].itemName,
        sellerUsername: item[0].sellerUsername,
        price: item[0].price,
        image: item[0].image,
        itemId: item[0].itemId
    });
    }
    const order = new OrdersModel(
    orderItems
    );
}
```

Comment: Ahh, that makes perfect sense. I didn't know that. Thank you very much for the help!